# In App Billing, Get the subscription multiple times

Tags: android

I'm building an app that will allow creating subscriptions. In order to use the app you'll need to create an account.

I'm having trouble understanding how can I have multiple users on the same device buy the subscription without changing the device's Google account.

Thank you for your time!

Cheers

Comment: Any fixes for different app user to allow subscribing the same product on same device using same google play account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subscription purchased within the app will be assigned to the Google account that downloaded the app. There is no way to change this. You cannot create your own account system and assign your purchases to them.

If you have multiple users on the same device, each user would need their own Google account set up on the device (with their own credit card info) and would need to be signed in using that account at the time of purchase.

Comment: I just found this related article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284469/app-with-multiple-user-in-single-device-inapp-billing-subscription
I turns out there is no easy way to work around this.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that. The account owner would be paying for all of the subscriptions and not each user.  We have separate device user accounts for a reason.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I'll take that into consideration.